# async.parallel or Q.all which I've to use? How? + NodeJS

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, q, async.js

Hello I have the following code, I want to use `async.parallel` and `Q.all` function for parallel execution of functions calling.

Should I use or not Please reply, All your answers are appreciations.

```
function getPath(x){
    return (x/100);  // It's demo here it's some big logic exist.
}

var array = [4,56,2,3,34,45,65,23,23,12,12,23,34,43,54,54];  // lack of data in array
var resultArr = [];
array.forEach(function(val){
    resultArr.push(getPath(val));
})

// After 5-8 sec, I got results.
```

Can I execute the same things using `async.parellel` or `Q.all` How?

Comment: q.all, or rather Promise.all, nicer with async/await

Comment: @Endless How ? Can you please guide how can I use them with about scenario.

Comment: gave you a simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q and promises are able to mix, and you can even await Q promises that are A+ compatible. Here is an example using promises and another with async/await

```js
function readDir(x) {
    return new Promise(function(rs){
        setTimeout(rs, x, x)
    })
}

function getPath(x) {
    return readDir(x).then(function(val){
         return val / 100
    })
}

var array = [4,56,2,3,34,45,65,23,23,12,12,23,34,43,54,54];  // lack of data in array
var resultArr = array.map(function(val) {
    return getPath(val);
});

// Q.all is the equivulant of Promise.all
Promise.all(resultArr).then(console.log)
```

```js
function readDir(x) {
    return new Promise(function(rs){
        setTimeout(rs, x, x)
    })
}

async function getPath(x) {
    var val = await readDir(x)
    return val / 100;
}

async function init() {
  var array = [4,56,2,3,34,45,65,23,23,12,12,23,34,43,54,54];  // lack of data in array
  var resultArr = array.map(function(val) {
      return getPath(val);
  });
  
  var result = await Promise.all(resultArr);
  console.log(result)
}

init()
```

node v10 ships with [fs.promises](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) that are pretty neat.

```
async function getPath(x) {
   const files = await fs.promises.readdir(x)
   console.log(files)
}
```

all functions that are async returns a promise